# How to set default account-expiration date for all new users?

Tags: users, username, adduser

How can I set a default account-expiration-date for all new users?

I know we can do it for every new added user with the `--expiredate`, but I want that it is default and done for every new user!

like when I use `adduser someuser` and then I type `chage -l someuser` I want to find directly that the account expires after one year from the adding-day! 
'
Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use option `-D` to edit the default expiry date from command line:

```bsh
adduser -D --expiredate=2020-12-22
```

and to list the new defaults:

```bsh
adduser -D
```

Worked in Centos7

Comment: I do not see this option '-D' in the man pages of my version (ubuntu 18.04).  On which OP did you use this option?

Comment: Centos7, and yes I've checked Ubuntu now and it doesn't have it :D

Answer (score 0):

From `useradd` man page:

```
-e, --expiredate EXPIRE_DATE
     The date on which the user account will be disabled. The date is
     specified in the format YYYY-MM-DD.

     If not specified, useradd will use the default expiry date specified
     by the EXPIRE variable in /etc/default/useradd, or an empty string 
     (no expiry) by default.
```

So you should change the `EXPIRE` variable in the `/etc/default/useradd` to whatever value you like. The same applies for `adduser` that uses `useradd` in the background.